# Magento-workflow to development extension with Modman

Tags: magento, development-environment

I'm install modman in my personal computer to development a custom extension in Magento with the correspondly maintenance of this.
I want to know the correct workflow between Magento Module and Modman. I have one doubt in the process to update my extension.
To the complet understanding, I'll describe the workflow under my point of view:

1. Create My git repository for my extension

   in the server side:

   git init bare
2. Clone this repository and create the skeleton to modman script

   nano modman:

   code                            app/code/scope/company/Module/
   compamy_module.xml          app/etc/modules/company_module.xml
3. update the repository

   git add/commit/push
4. In my free install of Magento create new branch

   git checkout -b moduleName
5. Clone the extension in my instalation

   modman clone git@x.x.x.x:/route/to/module/repository

Ok, in this point I have a good enviorment to work with my Magento module extension, but I have the next doubt. Who I can update the module repository working from the magento free installation??
I try 
`modman update moduleName`

but I don't update the repository of the extension, How Is the correct Workflow?
Should I modify the extension repository?
I think that can work from the Magento clean installation and update the Magento module repository from that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this:

1. make your extension repo (bare or not does not matter, bare is suggested as a master repository)
2. create modman script like you did (your does not look like a proper extension one)
3. update the repo
4. on your magento installation you can checkout your branch or use master branch (separate workflow)
5. modman clone .....
6. go back to 3. add your changes and push to repo
7. modman update moduleName

Comment: In the third point, you refer update manually the extension repository. Then I development in my magento installation with my custom extensio, next copy this changes to extension repository and update(push),in the last step modman update.

Comment: essence of GIT is : change > commit > push (if remote) so yes you have to repeat that every time you chnage something and then you can PULL (update) from your modman script

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can work since Magento installation and work bidirectional between Magento and Module.  the workflow Magento Module==(modman update)=>Magento installation